# How to read only inner segments of a file using NIO

Tags: java, nio

My batch process needs to be reading lines from huge files (1-3G), each of which can be processed independently of another.  The files can have 10-50M rows.  I was thinking of spawning about a dozen threads each of which would be processing a predetermined range of buffers, e.g. T1 will read range 0-1, T2 1-2, etc. concurrently.  That means, of course, that T2 needs to jump instantly into the buffer position 2, without reading 0-2.

Is this type of segmentation of buffered file reading for the purposes of concurrency possible with Java NIO?

Comment: You can use RandomAccessFile and seek() to jump in files, but that's based on byte offsets so you'd need more processing if you need the buffer to jump to 'line 10M'.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to this. The CPU may allow multiple threads but the disk is still single-threaded. All this will do is cause disk thrashing. Forget it.